# Publishing on facebook using open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

This is Sasikumar A, I created the app for Galatta and i added the following details in web page head section

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="123225854445872"><meta property="og:type"        content="galatta-new:news"> <meta property="og:url"         content="http://v3.galatta.com/tamil/news/tamannaah-the-golden-girl/39536/"><meta property="og:title"       content="Tamannaah: The golden girl"> <meta property="og:description" content="Tamannaah: The golden girl"> <meta property="og:image"       content="http://v3.galatta.com/community/images/logo.png"> <meta property="og:site_name" content="Galatta.com" /><meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" /></head><body><div id="fb-root"></div>{literal}<script>(function(d){  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}  js =d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=123225854445872&xfbml=1";  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);}(document));</script>{/literal}<div     class="fb-like" data-href="{$HTTP_REFERER}" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"
data-font="tahoma"></div></body></html>
```

Link : http://v3.galatta.com/tamil/news/tamannaah-the-golden-girl/39536/

I created the Open Graph action type, object type, aggregations for Galatta App.

In action type i got the code for - See all your Read actions:, Create a new Read action:, Delete a Read action:

Please tell me how to use this code in my web page.

I need while i click the Like button I need result like below / or how to work for below result.

Sasi Arjun read "Tamannaah: The golden girl" on Galatta

Please guide me how to publish the page on Facebook like above line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/) is a really nice tutorial on exactly that topic.

If you are asking about the "code" links next to the action types in the Open Graph Developer tool: These serve just as an example, as you can invoke your actions via curl.

Your website would have to send these requests, e.g. using [PHP](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) on your server, or in the client's browser using the [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).